# LINQ to sort a List of Objects

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I'm having a `List<Clinics>` which has a property (another class) called `List<Doctors>`. Each `Doctors` has a property called `AverageCost`. I want to create a LINQ to sort the `List<Clinics>` based on Lowest average cost across all the Doctors and `ThenBy`  `ClinicID`. 
I've tried using

```
clinics = clinics.OrderBy(f => {
    f.Doctors = f.Doctors.OrderBy(p => p.AverageCost).ToList();
    return f;
})
.ThenBy(f => f.ClinicId).ToList();
```

And also

```
clinics = (from t in clinics select t).OrderBy(x => x.Doctors.OrderBy(z => z.AverageCost)).ToList();
```

But nothing seems to work. Please advise where I'm wrong. Thanks

Comment: Don't you just need the Min cost, i.e. `clinics.OrderBy(c => c.Doctors.Select(d => d.AverageCost).Min()).ThenBy(c => c.ClinicId)`

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve] with sample inputs and expected results based on those sample inputs.

Answer (score 3):

The reason that your implementations do not work is that `OrderBy` expects each element to return a single "thing" by which the elements could be compared. Your implementations return lists, which do not have a built-in way to be compared to each other.

You don't need to order doctors by average cost, just pick the lowest cost using `Min()` function:

```
clinics = clinics
    .OrderBy(f => f.Doctors.Min(d => d.AverageCost))
    .ThenBy(f => f.ClinicId)
    .ToList();
```

Comment: This still doesn't work as in my test data I'm having a single Clinic which has 2 doctors and the average cost of first is 4 whereas the average cost of second is 3. The output still has the first doctor (with Average cost as 4) instead of 3.

Comment: @Amar This sorts only clinics, not doctors within clinics. A clinic that has a doctor with the lowest cost will be first in the sorted list, but the doctor itself may not be the first doctor on the clinic's list. You need to sort doctors separately when preparing the clinic for display, using whatever technology you use for your user interface.

Answer (score 1):

So every Clinic has zero or more Doctors. Every Doctor has a property AverageCost.

> I want to sort the Clinics based on Lowest average cost across all the
>   Doctors

Do you mean the lowest average of (average costs of the Doctor), or do you want to order by the Cheapest Doctor = the Doctor with the lowest average cost?

```
Clinic A:
   Doctor A1: Average cost 10
   Doctor A2: Average cost 50
Clinic B:
   Doctor B1: Average cost 25
   Doctor B2: Average cost 15
```

Doctor A1 is the cheapest doctor of ClinicA with an average cost of 10. Doctor B2 is the cheapest doctor of ClinicB with an average cost of 25.

If sorting on "Lowest average cost across all the Doctors" means that you want to sort by the cheapest doctor, you get Clinic A followed by Clinic B

If "Lowest average cost across all the Doctors" means the average of the AverageCosts per Clinic, you get that ClinicA has Average costs over all doctors (10+50)/2 = 30; ClinicB has average costs over all doctors of (25+15)/2 = 20. You'd take first ClinicB, then ClinicA

So which one do you want?

**Order by the cheapest Doctor**

```
var result = Clinics.Select(clinic => new
{
     CheapestDoctor = clinic.Doctors
          .OrderBy(doctor => doctor.AverageCost)
          .FirstOrDefault(),
     Clinic = clinic,
})
.OrderBy(clinic => clinic.CheapestDoctor.AverageCost)
.Select(clinic => clinic);
```

(TODO: decide what to do with Clinics without doctors)

**Order by overall lowest Average**

```
var result = Clinics.Select(clinic => new
{
     OverallAverage = clinic.Doctors
          .Select(doctor => doctor.AverageCost)
          .Average(),
     Clinic = clinic,
})
.OrderBy(clinic => clinic.OverallAverage)
.Select(clinic => clinic);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I want to SORT based on the cheapest doctor available. So for your example, I'll be getting the output as: A1, B2, B1, A2

Comment: ******Correction******* I realized my mistake, I was expecting a single Clinics object (with 2 doctors, average cost: 20 and 40) to be split into two and  a second Clinics object to be sandwiches (avarage cost 30). Sorry about the whole confusion. Thanks a lot to everyone for help, time and effort.